# c++ swapping content of array - Selection Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, dynamic-memory-allocation, selection-sort, function-declaration

I'm new to C++. I was attempting to write a function for selection sort the following way.

```
void selection_sort(int* m[], int array_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) 
      int min_ind = i;
      for (int j = i+1; j < array_size; j++){
        if (m[min_ind] > m[j]){
            min_ind = j;
        }
      }
      int temp = *m[i];
      *m[i] = *m[min_ind];
      *m[min_ind] = temp;
    }
  }
```

Within main, the array is defined as:

```
int *sel_nums = new int[n];
```

And I'm calling selection sort in main:

```
selection_sort( &sel_nums, x );
```

I keep getting an error that says:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does anyone have any input on why this keeps happening?

Comment: `int* m[]` This is an array of `int` pointers. You almost certainly meant `int* m` or `int m[]` instead.

Comment: I suspect that you don't need to pass in a pointer to the array. It's not like you are changing where that pointer points. In `m[min_ind] > m[j]` you are comparing addresses in an array rather than the values at those addresses.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a pretty good page on selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) complete with code you can adapt to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocated dynamically an array of objects of the type `int`.

```
int *sel_nums = new int[n];
```

This array you are going to pass to the function `selection_sort`. So the function declaration will look at ;east like

```
void selection_sort( int m[], int array_size );
```

The compiler implicitly adjust the parameter having the array type to pointer to the array element type. That is the above declaration is equivalent to

```
void selection_sort( int *m, int array_size );
```

So the function can be called like

```
selection_sort( sel_nums, n );
```

To swap two elements of the array within the function you can write

```
  if ( min_ind != i )
  {
      int temp = m[i];
      m[i] = m[min_ind];
      m[min_ind] = temp;
  }
```

Or you could use the standard C++ function `std::swap` like

```
#include <utility>

//...

if ( min_ind != i )
{
    std::swap( m[i], m[min_ind] );
}
```